# Module import loads wrong assembly version

Tags: powershell, dll, dllimport

I have a module manifest that specifies an explicit path to some Visual Studio 2015 assemblies (version 14.0.0.0) in the "RequiredAssemblies" array. After running Import-Module I am getting the 12.0.0.0 version assemblies added to the session instead.

```
RequiredAssemblies = @(
    "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
)
```

After running the following command:

```
[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | sort -property fullname | format-table fullname
```

I can see that only the 12.0.0.0 version of the assembly was added to my current session:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

I have ensured that the *.dll at the path is the version I am looking for... Why is powershell forcing the previous version? Is there any way to prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Check the `Location` of the loaded assemblies as well -- and make sure no version of this assembly is already loaded before you import the module. If necessary, you can get to the gory details by using the [assembly binding log viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e74a18c4). Make sure to log successful binds as well as unsuccessful ones. My money is on something loading the "old" version as a dependency somewhere before your requirement kicks in.

Comment: The assembly binding log viewer didn't display anything for me and the assembly location is being loaded from the .NET directory under the windows folder. This doesn't surprise me because it is not loading the assembly I have targeted.

Comment: The assembly binding log viewer can display *any* binding for *any* .NET application -- including PowerShell. I do recall configuring it to really log everything can be tricky, though. But rest assured, if an assembly is getting loaded and it's not getting logged, it's a configuration issue.

Comment: "Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified." But the path is correct...